# Adding a grid as a below the edit form in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I have `User` that has many `Post`s.
Bellow the `User` edit form I want to show the related `Post`s grid.

The following function will bring the related posts.
How can I combine it above/inside/bellow the edit `User` form?

I know this function will work, just don't know how to combine it.

```
// user crud controller

    public function getUserRlatedPosts($user_id)
    {

        $crud = new CrudPanel();
        $crud->addClause('where', 'user_id', '=', $user_id);
        $crud->setModel("post");
        $crud->setEntityNameStrings("post","posts");
        $crud->enableAjaxTable();

        $this->data['crud'] = $crud;
        $this->data['title'] = ucfirst($this->crud->entity_name_plural);
        if (! $this->data['crud']->ajaxTable()) {
            $this->data['entries'] = $this->data['crud']->getEntries();
        }
        return view('crud::list', $this->data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Backpack\CRUD 3.2.x you can use a custom view with the following methods:

```
$this->crud->setShowView('your-view');
$this->crud->setEditView('your-view');
$this->crud->setCreateView('your-view');
$this->crud->setListView('your-view');
$this->crud->setReorderView('your-view');
$this->crud->setRevisionsView('your-view');
$this->crud->setRevisionsTimelineView('your-view');
$this->crud->setDetailsRowView('your-view');
```

and specify the view in which you also include that form.

Comment: Thanks, I already know that. but I don't understand how can that be achieved? should I move the vendor's views to my views folder and change that? can you provide some explanations? maybe pseudo code?
I did not see anything close to that in the docs or in the git issues. thanks again

Comment: Hi Shazam. Nope, just create a /vendor/backpack/crud folder in your /resources/ . That will do it. Then place a single file you want to customize there.